# map to AnyPublisher Void

Tags: swift, combine

I have a function that takes a publisher parameterlike this

```
func runPublisher(publisher: AnyPublisher<Void, Error>, shouldLoad: Bool = true) {

}
```

When I try to convert to publisher, I get this error

```
let publisher = provider.check(credentials: cred)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
            .tryMap({ (data) in
            })
            .mapError({ (error) -> Error in
                return error
            })
            .map { _ in

                return ()
            }

runPublisher(publisher: publisher)
```

I get the error

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Publishers.Map<Publishers.MapError<Publishers.TryMap<AnyPublisher<BaseResponseData<AuthResponse>, MoyaError>, ()>, Error>, ()>' to expected argument type 'AnyPublisher<Void, Error>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use .eraseToAnyPublisher

```
let publisher = provider.check(credentials: cred)
        .tryMap({ (data) in
        })
        .mapError({ (error) -> Error in
            return error
        })
        .map { _ in

            return ()
        }
.eraseToAnyPublisher()
```